# Query is not returning data after adding my code in a view

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written below code snippet in my application view but its taking long time to fetched the result and after 2-3 hours of time its giving Table space issue. What is better way to write below query. Since i have to use existing code for this requirement.

Below  is the requirement.

We have to check last 30 days from the latest statement date w.r. to account using following formula

```
if ((sum of credits for 30 days from the latest statement date w.r. to account/sum debits for 30 days from the latest statement date w.r. to account)-sum debits for 30 days from the latest statement date w.r. to account)>0 then YES else NO
```

My view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW <View_Name> AS
SELECT <List of columns names>,

    (SELECT 
            CASE WHEN ((SUM(DECODE(CR_DR_FLAG,'C',TRANSACTION_AMT,NULL))/DECODE(SUM(DECODE(CR_DR_FLAG,'D',TRANSACTION_AMT,NULL)),0,1))
            -SUM(DECODE(CR_DR_FLAG,'D',TRANSACTION_AMT,NULL)))>0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
            ROLL_C_D FROM SWIFT_TRANSACTION_DETAILS WHERE  CLEAN_SWIFT_ACCT = T_ROLL.SWIFT_ACCT 
            AND CURRENCY_CODE= T_ROLL.CUR AND STATEMENT_DATE BETWEEN  (T_ROLL.STATEMENT_DATE_LATEST-30) AND T_ROLL.STATEMENT_DATE_LATEST 
            GROUP BY CLEAN_SWIFT_ACCT,CURRENCY_CODE ) CR_ACTIVITY_FLAG
  --My Code End         

  FROM
    (SELECT <List of columns names>
    FROM TEMP_BATS_METRIC_REPORT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT <List of columns names>
    FROM VIEW_BATS_METRICS_REPORT
    WHERE MATCHING_STATUS IN('MATCHED TO ARA RECON','Unmatched')
    ) T_ROLL --alias give to 2 tables union all
  ORDER BY MATCHING_STATUS,
    TO_NUMBER(ACT_ID),
    ACCOUNT_MATCHING_TYPE,
    SWIFT_ACCT;
```

Comment: Can you post the query plan too please

Comment: Your code is a Scalar Subquery and will fail if it returns more than a single row, i.e more than one `CURRENCY_CODE` per `CLEAN_SWIFT_ACCT`. Scalar Subqueries tend to have bad optimization, try rewriting as an (Outer) Join to a  Derived Table (Inline View in Oracle lingo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs to be converted into joins and I have tried re-writing it as following:

```
SELECT
    <List of columns names - SELECT>,
    CASE
        WHEN ( CR_ACTIVITY_FLAG_C / CASE CR_ACTIVITY_FLAG_D
            WHEN 0   THEN 1
        END ) - CR_ACTIVITY_FLAG_D > 0 THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
    END AS CR_ACTIVITY_FLAG
-- ADDED ABOVE SELECT CLAUSE
FROM ( SELECT <List of columns names - SELECT>,

  --My Code Start -- ADDED FOLLOWING 2 
    SUM(DECODE(CR_DR_FLAG,'C',TRANSACTION_AMT,NULL)) AS CR_ACTIVITY_FLAG_C,
    SUM(DECODE(CR_DR_FLAG,'D',TRANSACTION_AMT,NULL)) AS CR_ACTIVITY_FLAG_D,
  --My Code End         

  FROM
    (SELECT <List of columns names>
    FROM TEMP_BATS_METRIC_REPORT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT <List of columns names>
FROM
    VIEW_BATS_METRICS_REPORT
WHERE
    MATCHING_STATUS IN (
        'MATCHED TO ARA RECON',
        'Unmatched'
    )
    ) T_ROLL --alias give to 2 tables union all
-- ADDED FOLLOWING JOIN AND JOIN CONDITIONS
LEFT JOIN SWIFT_TRANSACTION_DETAILS STD 
ON ( CLEAN_SWIFT_ACCT = T_ROLL.SWIFT_ACCT
    AND CURRENCY_CODE = T_ROLL.CUR
        AND STATEMENT_DATE BETWEEN ( T_ROLL.STATEMENT_DATE_LATEST - 30 ) AND T_ROLL.STATEMENT_DATE_LATEST
        )
-- ADDED FOLLOWING GROUP BY
GROUP BY <List of columns names - SELECT>,
CLEAN_SWIFT_ACCT,
CURRENCY_CODE )
ORDER BY
    MATCHING_STATUS,
    TO_NUMBER(ACT_ID),
    ACCOUNT_MATCHING_TYPE,
    SWIFT_ACCT;
```

Hope, This will help you in finding the direction to solve the issue.

Cheers!!

Comment: That's really helped...Thank You!! SUM(DECODE(CR_DR_FLAG,'C',TRANSACTION_AMT,NULL)) is taking longer time to fetch the records and not giving any output.